# How to take a database backup to a binary file in MySQL using phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin user interface to mysql database.

I want to take a full database backup, and if possible then a compressed one.

I know that I can export the database into a `.sql` file. How to take a full database backup into a binary file?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to click the "Custom - display all possible options" radio button to see more export options. From that page, you can find the available compression types in the "Output" area when selecting to save the output as a file.

[image: Export page]

Personally, I prefer to script this and use a cron job to run mysqldump (which I then pipe to xz), but this works just fine. The available compression options may vary depending on what is available in your PHP installation.

I will also point out here for the sake of completeness that you've asked another question elsewhere about a large database, and using phpMyAdmin to export a compressed file of a large database can sometimes be more problematic than exporting a .sql file directly and compressing that yourself (because of the additional memory overhead of streaming to the compression algorithm).